# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, коллекции, итераторы

```
public class StudentMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        StudentService ss = new StudentService();
        List<Student<Integer,String,Integer,Double,Boolean>> students = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
            students.add(new Student<>(ss.getNumber(),ss.getNameFromFileOutSide(), ss.getAge(), ss.getRating(),ss.getOlympic()));
        }
        List<Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean>> ageEqualOrHigherTwelve;
        ageEqualOrHigherTwelve = students;

        Iterator<Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean>> iterator = ageEqualOrHigherTwelve.iterator();
        for (Iterator<Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean>> it = iterator; it.hasNext(); ) {
            Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean> student = it.next();
            if (student.getA()>=12&&student.getR()>=8) {
                ageEqualOrHigherTwelve.add(student);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ageEqualOrHigherTwelve);

    }
    }
```

Почему выбрасывает исключение? И как исправить ?

Comment: `ageEqualOrHigherTwelve.add(student);` - Это зачем?

Comment: Мне надо первую коллекцию students отфильтровать по getA и getR. И если условие верно, то во вторую коллекцию добавить нужный объект. Тут не смотрите, что вторая коллекция инициализирована первой, это чисто попытки были.

Comment: Нельзя менять коллекцию по которой движется итератор. Единственное исключение - методы самого итератора.

Comment: Тогда как мне в таком случае поступить ?

Comment: Пока итерируетесь накапливайте объекты во временной коллекции. Когда итерация завершится, добавляйте из временной в основную.

Comment: "Тут не смотрите," - ну, минус тогда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Почему выбрасывает исключение?*

Потому что код делает всё для этого -- коллекция `ageEqualOrHigherTwelve` по сути тот же список `student`, для итерации по которому используется итератор, и в таком случае результат итерации при изменении списка студентов может быть непредсказуем.

Если нужно получить отфильтрованный список студентов по данному условию, достаточно просто создать новый результирующий список:

```java
List<Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean>> ageEqualOrHigherTwelve = new ArrayList<>();
```

тогда в него можно спокойно добавлять подходящие значения.

Или же можно просто использовать Stream  API, не создавая итератор:

```java
List<Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean>> ageEqualOrHigherTwelve = students
    .stream()
    .filter(student -> student.getA() >= 12 && student.getR() >= 8)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ageEqualOrHigherTwelve = new ArrayList<>();

Iterator<Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean>> iterator = students.iterator();
```